# metachange event is not fired

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a store, which looks like this:

```
Ext.define('GridGeneral.store.GridGeneralStore',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'GridGeneral.model.GridGeneralModel',
    autoLoad:true,
    proxy:{
         type:'ajax',
         url:'/api/grid/gridgeneralstore.php',
         reader:{
             type:'json'
         }            
    }
});
```

Inside a controller I want to fire `metachange' event. I try to do it like this:

```
init:function(){
    Ext.getStore('GridGeneralStore').addListener('metachange',this.metaChanged, this); 
    //^^^not fired
    Ext.getStore('GridGeneralStore').addListener('load',this.loaded, this);
    //^^^ this is ok
},
metaChanged:function(store, meta){
    console.log('metaChanged');  // see nothing in the colsole   
},
loaded:function(){
    console.log('loaded');    // everything works fine! 
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metachange event is only fired when *rolldrum* metadata has changed. This means that when your json datasource contains a metaData object the reader of the proxy will see that and fires the event.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-property-metaData

JSON:

```
{
  data: [{ ... }],
  msg: "...",
  total: 99,
  metaData: {
    fields: [{ ... }],
    columns: [{ ... }],
    idProperty: "id",
    messageProperty: "msg",
    root: "data"
  }
}
```

Example:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/examples/data/meta-config-basic.html

Comment: That the event was not fired is an useful thing. For example, if you are using a buffered grid or a paging toolbar you only want to sent metadata the first time you call to the server. Your backend could then only send metadata when page is one, and your grid needs to be reconfigured or your model needs additional fields.