# Sencha ExtJs: modify a store/model to handle records partially

Tags: extjs, model, proxy, callback, store

I've got a combobox which is being filled in via http request. For this a JsonStore with proxy is used, and the model is defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('TreeModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'field_1',
        'field_2'
    ]
});
```

This worked perfectly fine with the following responses, provided I used `rootProperty: 'data'` in the reader:

```
{
    "data":[{"field_1":1,"field_2":318},
            {"field_1":2,"field_2":322}]
}
```

Now I am to add some database error handling by adding error description like:

```
{
    "data": [{"field_1":1,"field_2":318},
             {"field_1":2,"field_2":322}],
    "error":{"code":"0","message":null}
}
```

, so thah I could do something like:

```
TreeStore.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                 App.checkServerReply(records[0].data.error);
              }
});
```

Is there any way to modify the model or store or whatever so that it was either possible to obtain  error description somewhat in the way shown and to continue filling in the combobox from the data array? Any other ideas to obtain the solution without modifying the response format?

Comment: Can't you use the `metachange` event for this, what will be fired when the `metadata object` is present in your JSON? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382790/metachange-event-is-not-fired/31382971#31382971

Comment: Alas, it is  undesirable to change the format of JSON for certain reasons. But thank you for advice - that's surely another useful thing I didn't know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method `load` you could do actually this:

```
TreeStore.load({
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        var data = Ext.JSON.decode(operation._response.responseText);
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(data.error)) {
            var error = data.error;
            //do your stuff with error.code and error.message
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

`Records[0]` cannot contain your result because you don't send it as part of the first result record. In fact, you send it as metadata, but there are no well-defined and documented functions to access transmitted metadata (although I guess everyone sends it at some time).

In ExtJS 4.2.2, I am using the following:

```
store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        var rawData = store.getProxy().getReader().rawData;
        //Ext.MessageBox.alert(rawData.Caption, rawData.Message);
        App.checkServerReply(rawData.error);
    }
});
```

Although not asked, I would like to point out that sencha allows you to use `success` and `failure` instead of `callback`, if you deliver a `success` flag from the server:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data": [{"field_1":1,"field_2":318},
             {"field_1":2,"field_2":322}],
    "error":{"code":"0","message":null}
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Two different answers for single question from you and Paweł Głowacz are marvellous and show me that there is so mush still not learned in ExtJs. Wish I could mark both as solutions, but alas - had to choose the first just by timing.

Comment: PS Is `store.getProxy().getReader().rawData` secure concerning race condition? And `callback` is mostly used because it is not possible right now to edit message format, but thanks for the info!