# Create dynamic model

Tags: javascript, extjs, dynamic, model

Hello Guys im stugeling with an dynamic model i need a loop to create the columns, i found just this "items.push({" but i dont know how to use it. 
can anybody help me please.

```
onSqlChange: function (gridPanel, value) {
    var me = this;

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '{url action=getSqlDetails}',
        params: {
            fileName: value
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var text = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            console.log(text);
            me.mainWindow.grid.show();
            var columns = [];
            Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {
                items: columns
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This the return from : `JSON.parse(response.responseText);`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`model`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) doesn't have a property `items`. Your `grid` does have a `store`, that `store` has a `model` and that `model` has `fields`. Your `grid` has `columns`.

Try [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) your grid with the columns you retrieve with your ajax call:

```
onSqlChange: function (gridPanel, value) {
    var me = this;

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '{url action=getSqlDetails}',
        params: {
            fileName: value
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var text = JSON.parse(response.responseText),
                grid = me.mainWindow.grid,
                columns = text.columns;

            grid.reconfigure(columns);
            grid.show();
        }
    });
}
```

But imo it can be done much cleaner. Columns and fields can be dynamically set in the `metachange` event. When you listen to this you can from that place reconfigure your grid with the store and the columns. In `onSqlChange` you only have to load your store again (which will lead to firing `metachange` and reconfigures your grid).

More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31382971/408487

Comment: Nice solution it seems to work :) thank u!  have u maybe an idea about an dynamic store ?

Comment: What do you mean about a dynamic store?

Comment: I need an store for my grid which load the data, or can i renounce it here ?

Comment: Why not creating a store what will retrieve your sql data?In the metachange reconfigure the grid with this store, and columns from the metadata. You only have to load your store after that and you grid is reconfigured with the new data from the store and the new columns from the metadata. Please read this for more architecture: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/mvc_pt2

Comment: damn i cant use addlListener cause i have extJs 4.1 :/

Comment: Maybe create a new question and provide us with the code you are using (in a Sencha Fiddle)? But `addListener` on which object? The store does have a `addListener`: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-addListener